# Spark Kafka - Issue while running from Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am experimenting with Spark Kafka integration. And I want to test the code from my eclipse IDE. However, I got below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
    at kafka.utils.Pool.<init>(Pool.scala:28)
    at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$.<init>(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:60)
    at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$.<clinit>(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(SimpleConsumer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.connect(KafkaCluster.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:342)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers(KafkaCluster.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitionMetadata(KafkaCluster.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitions(KafkaCluster.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:532)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
    at com.capiot.platform.spark.SparkTelemetryReceiverFromKafkaStream.executeStreamingCalculations(SparkTelemetryReceiverFromKafkaStream.java:248)
    at com.capiot.platform.spark.SparkTelemetryReceiverFromKafkaStream.main(SparkTelemetryReceiverFromKafkaStream.java:84)
```

**UPDATE:**
The versions that I am using are:

- scala - 2.11
- spark-streaming-kafka- 1.4.1
- spark - 1.4.1

Can any one resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong version of Scala. You need 2.10.x per

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/

"For the Scala API, Spark 1.4.1 uses Scala 2.10."

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to help OP, but when using kafka streaming with spark, you need to make sure that you use the right jar file.

For example, in my case, I have scala 2.11 (the minimum required for spark 2.0 which im using), and given that kafka spark requires the version 2.0.0 I have to use the artifact `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.0.0-preview.jar`

Notice my scala version and the artifact version can be seen at `2.11-2.0.0`

Hope this helps (someone)

Hope that helps.